# How does the Instruments stop working automatically?

Tags: iphone, debugging, instruments, allocation

I try to monitor the allocation through Instruments.

However, when I run to a point, sending some jabber msg, the Instruments stop working automatically.

I wonder how does it stop.

Is there any code in an app could stop the Instruments?

Comment: I have variation of this problem: How do I make instruments stop at certain point? is there some option to  make it stop when UIA script finishes?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem too. The answer i got was: Instruments does stop if your memory usage is too high. Turn on Allocations, and see the memory usage. In my app, I was calling web services, which were downloading some heavy data, because of which my app's memory consumption would go unto like, 60-70 MB, (for an iPad app). This was causing instruments to crash.

So I had to put some memory fixes. I was able to reduce it to around 12 MB. And then Instruments resumed to work fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be as @Cory Kilger suggests and the app is crashing.

Try running it outside of instruments.

Good luck :)